# Why Australian residents are barred from Salesforce Trailhead Sweepstakes?

Tags: trailhead

I spent quite sometime in completing one of the challenges needed for the competition so that I can be part of the sweepstakes.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/offers/new-years-2017

After spending quite some time I went through the fine print and it looks like Salesforce (for reasons unknown) has decided to exclude Oz residents from the sweepstakes.

[image]

Is there any reason behind this ?

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer to this question here.

Comment: The reason has to do with *law*, actually. It's really hard to run even a national sweepstakes. I can't imagine how much they had to pay lawyers to get the sweepstakes in 11 countries. You might try asking on [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/), as the people there seriously spend too much time looking up laws, regulations, and case law.

Comment: Yeah I have to leave this closed this because it's off-topic, but I don't think I've ever seen a competition from Salesforce where I've been able to enter as an Australian, same goes for almost all US based compo in my experience.